# Wiring for Broan-Nutone roomside bath exhaust fan with humidistat?

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

I have the NuTone® Roomside 110 CFM Humidity Sensing Decorative Ventilation Fan with Round Flat Panel LED Light - model aern110slw.

https://www.broan-nutone.com/en-us/product/ventilationfans/aern110slw

My previous fan had two switches - one to control the fan, and the other to control the light. I would like to wire this fan the same way, and bypass the humidistat.

- The switch for the fan wiring is wht/blk/grnd.
- The switch for the light wiring is wht/red/blk/grnd.

I'm finding the wiring diagram included with the fan a bit confusing, especially in relation to the bypassing of the humidistate (the gray "optional" wire).

Update:

- I figured out part of the issue. The prior fan had a nightlight, so needed the secondary hot (red). But the new fan does not need the red, so I have the light working on the unit correctly.
- I also have the non-bypass (no grey wire) connection working correctly (double flip the switch to get it to be manual instead of humidistat), but I just want separate fan control (no humidistat), so I'm unsure of where to connect the gray wire.

[image: wiring diagram]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the ceiling you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -  I can, but the ceiling is wht/blk/grnd, and wht/red/blk/grnd - same as to the switches.